# Odoo Issue partner.active

Tags: odoo

I'm using Odoo 15 community.

I have this error during many manipulation like reconcile, send email with custom model.

This is my error in odooDB

2023-08-03 13:24:12.933 UTC [587] ERROR:  column "partner.active" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function at character 670

2023-08-03 13:24:12.933 UTC [587] STATEMENT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pid) * FROM (

    WITH sub_followers AS (

        SELECT fol.partner_id,

               coalesce(subtype.internal, false) as internal

          FROM mail_followers fol

          JOIN mail_followers_mail_message_subtype_rel subrel ON subrel.mail_followers_id = fol.id

          JOIN mail_message_subtype subtype ON subtype.id = subrel.mail_message_subtype_id

         WHERE subrel.mail_message_subtype_id = 5

           AND fol.res_model = 'account.move'

           AND fol.res_id IN (466)



     UNION ALL



        SELECT id,

               FALSE

          FROM res_partner

         WHERE id=ANY('{}')

    )

    SELECT partner.id as pid,

           partner.active as active,

           partner.partner_share as pshare,

           users.notification_type AS notif,

           array_agg(groups_rel.gid) AS groups

      FROM res_partner partner

 LEFT JOIN res_users users ON users.partner_id = partner.id

                          AND users.active

 LEFT JOIN res_groups_users_rel groups_rel ON groups_rel.uid = users.id

      JOIN sub_followers ON sub_followers.partner_id = partner.id

                        AND (NOT sub_followers.internal OR partner.partner_share IS NOT TRUE)

        GROUP BY partner.id,

                 users.notification_type

) AS x

ORDER BY pid, notif
```

it's like a problem with mail module but no luck to find problem.

odoo community version 15.0-20230710
mail module version 15.0.1.5

Answer (score 0):

It's an SQL error that comes from this part

```sql
    SELECT partner.id as pid,
           partner.active as active,
           partner.partner_share as pshare,
           users.notification_type AS notif,
           array_agg(groups_rel.gid) AS groups
```

and means that if you are using an aggregated function over some elements of the select like you are doing with this part `array_agg(groups_rel.gid) AS groups`... then you need to put the non aggregated elements of the select into the group by and you already have put some of them

```sql
        GROUP BY partner.id,
                 users.notification_type
```

but there are still 2 more elements from the select that aren't in the group by

```sql
partner.active as active,
partner.partner_share as pshare,
```

So to solve it just add them to the group by part like this

```sql
        GROUP BY partner.id,
                 partner.active,
                 partner.partner_share,
                 users.notification_type
```